# RequireJS: How to declare dependencies on module level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I am trying to write a RequireJS module that depends on jQuery and a jQuery plugin. I am having trouble to declare these dependencies on module level & settings up the shim config – maybe I missed something, but this how I am trying it:

In my application config, I set the path to my module

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        // loads modules/myModule.js
        myModule: 'modules/myModule',
    }
});
require(['app']);
```

Which should now be available in `app.js`:

```
define(['myModule'], function (mm) {
    // Do stuff with myModule, now available as mm here
});
```

But how do declare the dependencies for my module – jQuery and the plugin?

I found [this wonderful wiki entry](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module) where multiple possibilities are shown, but I don't see how that could fit into my module?

I already got this defined in a separate file:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        jquery: 'path/to/jquery',
        plugin: 'path/to/plugin'
    },
    shim: {
        plugin: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

From the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config):

> Also, you can define the config object as the global variable require before require.js is loaded, and have the values applied automatically. This example specifies some dependencies to load as soon as require.js defines require():

But where should I put this configuration? Including it before `require.js` seems a bit contra-productive – if there are 10 modules with dependencies, then I would need to include 10 separate config files?

Answer (score 3):

Dependencies are usually defined in the same file as the actual module is defined. `shim` config is only needed for scripts that are not AMD modules.

Example of a module that has four dependencies:

myModule.js

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'plugin', 
    'lib/pluginFrom3rdParty',
    'anotherModule'
], function($, plugin, pluginFrom3rdParty, anotherModule) {
     // instantiate the module and possibly return a value as the exported value for the module.
})
```

Comment: Okay, but this would mean I define my dependencies on module level and in my application config I set the correct paths & shim config? That way I would break the module's portability quite a bit, don't you think? On the other hand, I am aware that it probably gets compiled later on.

Comment: I think it's pretty logical, modules define what they need and the application config defines where to find it.